# Automatically Rename Columns in Pandas using string and number

Tags: python, pandas

I have the current DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 7,8], [-2, 10, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8, 9]], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
```

I am trying to automatically rename every other column so that the first two are `lo1`, `up1`, `lo2`, `up2`. This is just an example, but I was hoping for a way to develop this for an entire DataFrame of many columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient approach is to use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

cols = [f'{a}{b+1}' for b,a in  product(range(len(df. columns)//2), ['lo','up'])]

df.columns = cols
```

Output:

```
   lo1  up1  lo2  up2
0   -1    2    1    3
1    4    6    7    8
2   -2   10   11   13
3    5    6    8    9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 7,8], [-2, 10, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8, 9]], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])

max_nr = int(len(df.columns)/2)

for i in range(max_nr):
    df.rename(columns={'{}'.format(i*2):'lo{}'.format(i), '{}'.format(i*2+1):'hi{}'.format(i)}, inplace=True)
```

output:

|  | lo0 | hi0 | lo1 | hi1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| 2 | -2 | 10 | 11 | 13 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is longer compared to the concise solutions posted above, there is another method by defining a function named `col_namer` in which `col_size` corresponds to the number of columns in `DataFrame` and `names_list` is the list of strings with which you want to name your columns. As a result we have:

```
def col_namer(col_size, names_list):

  rep = len(names_list)
  col_names = []
  mul = col_size // rep
  rem = col_size % rep
  
  if rem == 0:
    for i in range(1, mul + 1):
      for j in names_list:
        col_names.append(j + str(i))

    return col_names

  else:
    for i in range(1, mul + 1):
      for j in names_list:
        col_names.append(j + str(i))
    for i in range(mul + 1, mul + rem + 2):
      for j in names_list:
        if len(col_names) < col_size:
          col_names.append(j + str(i))
          
    return col_names

df = pd.DataFrame([[-1, 2, 1, 3], [4, 6, 7,8], [-2, 10, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8, 9]], columns=['0', '1', '2', '3'])
df.columns = col_namer(df.shape[1], ['lo', 'up'])
df
```

Out:

```
  lo1 up1 lo2 up2
0  -1   2   1   3
1   4   6   7   8
2  -2  10  11  13
3   5   6   8   9
```